# В каких предложениях "неинтересно" является кратким прилагательным, а в каких предиктивным наречием?

Tags: грамматика, двусоставное-предложение, односоставное-предложение, предикативы

Большой толковый словарь

**НЕИНТЕРЕСНО**, нареч. 1. к Неинтересный (1 зн.). Н. рассказывать. Н. читать лекции. 2. в функц. сказ. **Об отсутствии интереса у кого-л. к чему-л.** Мне н. здесь. Совсем н., как она будет одета.

(1)  ***Мне неинтересно** ваше предложение.*

(2) *Ваше предложение  **мне неинтересно**.*

(3) *Ваше предложение  **для меня неинтересно**.*

(4) *Мне **здесь неинтересно**.*

**Примечание.** В безличном предложении ***неинтересно***  определяет **состояние** (отсутствие интереса), отнесенное к кому-либо и чему-либо. В двусоставном предложение ***неинтересно*** называет признак подлежащего. В некоторых случаях вид предложения зависит от **позиции** слова.